# socket returns -1 (errno 97) very seldom

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, udp, errno

I am running a c++ program which tries the following code:

```
socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)
```

However the above returns -1 once in a while (maybe 1 time in over 3000 runs) and errno shows:

```
Errno 97: Address family not supported by protocol
```

How is this possible? Running this line should yield the same result over and over again?

Comment: Is it possible there are multiple interfaces on the machine (LAN, Wi-Fi) and only some support IPv6, and you occasionally switch between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Asaf good thinking, I was assuming there were a problem with my code rather than the machine it was running on.

So I started to investigate the machines (on the test environment) and it turned out one of the machines was not configured properly so it always failed on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

It can also happen when an attempt is made to bind or connect a socket to a multicast address.